# AngularJS service parent separate reference

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm using an AngularJS service to store data from multiple pages, to be submitted together.  See the code below.

In my Chrome console if I observe `checkoutData.shipping`, I get back the correct object with data.  If I observe `checkoutData.data` I get an empty object, where it's shipping property is blank.

These should be pointing at the same object, right?  Why would it work with .shipping and not using .data?  The reason it's set up this way is that the shipping page only cares about .shipping, while the final page needs everything in .data.

```
(function() {
    angular.module('app').factory('checkoutData', [function() {
        var data = {
            carrierId: null,
            serviceTypeId: null,
            shippingCost: {},
            billingOptionId: null,
            shipping: {},
            billing: {},
            cart: null
        };
        var inputForms = {};
        var options = {
            shippingOptions: null,
            billingOptions: null,
            selectedShippingOption: null
        };
        var staticContent = {
            billing: {},
            cart: {},
            shipping: {}
        };
        return {
            data: data,
            shipping: data.shipping,
            inputForms: inputForms,
            cart: data.cart,
            billingOptionId: data.billingOptionId,
            billingOptions: options.billingOptions,
            carrierId: data.carrierId,
            serviceTypeId: data.serviceTypeId,
            shippingOptions: options.shippingOptions,
            staticContentBilling: staticContent.billing,
            staticContentCart: staticContent.cart,
            staticContentShipping: staticContent.shipping,
            selectedShippingOption: options.selectedShippingOption,
            setValid: function(formName, valid) {
                inputForms[formName].valid = valid;
            },
            initializeForm: function(formName) {
                inputForms[formName] = {};
            },
            formInitialized: function (formName) {
                return inputForms[formName] != null;
            }
        }
    }]);
})();
```

Comment: from where you console the value of them, a controller?

Comment: If you're using your factory in a controller you're getting for `checkoutData.shipping` an empty object because it's empty and for `checkoutData.data` you're getting the object `{shippingCost: {...},  shipping: {...}, ... }` Please have a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/bg7a56z3/).

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. There is no reason for `checkoutData.shipping` and `checkoutData.data.shipping` to be different right out of the factory. How do you "observe" the values ? And when ?

Comment: Are you sure you're manipulating your `shipping` object on the factory and not just reasssigning it to something else? Doing `checkoutData.shipping = x` anywhere else in your code is going to break the reference to your internal `data` variable. Maybe you shouldn't expose the properties at all but rather have getters and setters for them?

Comment: Alternatively, you could create two factories that consume the same data model but output data in different ways, one way for your shipping page and another for the "final" page. Your problem here is twofold: Databinding and trying to create an be-all-end-all data that can be consumed in many different ways. Why not modify the end pages to consume the data in the same way while you're at it? Mucking around with this mess instead seems rather silly and as you can see, overcomplicated.

Comment: My angularjs controllers are referencing my checkoutData service.  The "shipping: data.shipping" is used to make my references easier in my templates, so instead of ng-model="checkoutData.data.shipping.firstName" I can use ng-model="checkoutData.shipping.firstName".  I'm not familiar with using javascript getters/setters in angularJS services.  I'll look into it.

Comment: Yeah if you can I would just completely skip that shortcut. As you can see it just overcomplicates keeping track of object references, there's absolutely nothing wrong with `ng-model="checkoutData.data.shipping.firstName"` if you now absolutely need to have a `data` property. Alternatively, split it so `checkoutData` only contains the data. `checkout` could be the main factory with methods and such and `checkoutData` could be just your data model which you end up sending to the final page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One suggestion to make things easier is separate your data model(s) from your methods. And there's no need to try to keep multiple references to the same object within the same factory. There's nothing wrong with doing for example `ng-model="checkoutModule.data.shipping.firstName"`. Is it wordier? Yes. Is it wrong? No.

So maybe something like

```
angular.module('app').factory('checkoutData', [function() {
    return {
        dataModel: {
            carrierId: null,
            serviceTypeId: null,
            shippingCost: {},
            shipping: {}, // This should be databound to an object from "shippingOptions", removing the need for "selectedShippingOption"
            billing: {}, // This should be databound to an object from "billingOptions", removing the need for "billingOptionId"
            cart: null
        },
        options: {
            shippingOptions: null,
            billingOptions: null
        },
        inputForms: {}
    };
}]);
```

for your data and

```
angular.module('app').factory('checkoutModule', ['checkoutData', function(checkoutData) {
    return {
        data: checkoutData.dataModel,
        options: checkoutData.options,
        inputForms: checkoutData.inputForms,
        setValid: function(formName, valid) {
            checkoutData.inputForms[formName].valid = valid;
        },
        initializeForm: function(formName) {
            checkoutData.inputForms[formName] = {};
        },
        formInitialized: function (formName) {
            return checkoutData.inputForms[formName] != null;
        }
    }
}]);
```

for the factory that ties it all together.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see there is no way of setting the value of `data.shipping` other than using something like:

```
checkoutData.shipping = {"country" : "Sweden"};
```

This will result in `checkoutData.shipping` pointing to a new object and `checkoutData.shipping` will return that object:

```
{"country" : "Sweden"};
```

but 
`checkoutData.data` will return the original empty `shipping` object since we haven't updated that value.

If you instead create a function for setting the shipping value in the `checkoutData` service:

```
setShipping : function(s){
    data.shipping = s
},
```

and use that for setting the shipping data, you will get the values you want from `checkout.data` and `checkout.shipping`.

Have a look at this for demonstration: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guspersson/hw8oye69/)

Comment: If OP did `checkoutData.data.shipping =  {"country" : "Sweden"}` it should update the referenced object. But yeah, this seems like a very frail approach. Setters and getters would be preferential. Alternatively breaking that part out to its own service with databinding/setters.

Comment: My guess is, that's not what OP is doing though. And this data model just seems like a recipe for confusions such as this one.

Comment: @Jan setting the object to a new reference with checkoutData.data.shipping = {country: 'Sweden}; will NOT update the factory since it's a singleton and the value for checkoutData.shipping has already been assigned to the original reference. The only way to have it work is to either make checkoutData.shipping a method that always reads data.shipping or make it a getter property with Object.defineProperty or have a method setShipping that copies all properties of the passed object such that the original reference is maintained

Comment: I'm not sure I can use a separate getter and setter because I am doing 2-way data binding in my AngularJS templates.  My templates for example will have ng-model="checkoutData.shipping.firstName" and the 2 way binding works great.  When I set the data programatically I am doing it as you pointed out "checkoutData.shipping = { firstName: "Ryan" }" for example.  It does seem to be a case of data and data.shipping referencing different objects.